# Auto scale font size in CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got a paragraph of text. I do not want to overflow extra page when text length increases. Need to print always one page.

Is it possible to auto scale font size of text with css, in a div when the text size bigger than size of div?

The text will write by users. I dont have any idea about text length. But I dont want to give let them for to use more pages than one. Can set size of div, but can not set length of text. What is the best method for that?

Comment: is it fine if we reduce the font size ?

Comment: with javascript it is :)

Comment: oh yes.. pure CSS i doubt . if its Javascript probably i can give you some code snippet :)

Comment: @serhat: Are you open to using javascript?

Comment: @SerhatMERCAN: There. Added an answer.

Comment: [Mixing vw and vh in font-size](http://codepen.io/CrocoDillon/pen/fBJxu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32964004/auto-scale-font-size-in-css#comment53756625_32964004) you are open to use Javascript, hence proposing a Javascript solution (*actually using jQuery*). Hope you understand that this is not possible with only CSS.

All you need is to define your *threshold* for `height`. For example, if you decide that you need to accommodate your text in a `p` with a maximum height of `100px`, then you loop and keep reducing the `font-size` until the *threshold* height is reached.

Something like this:

```
var threshold = 100, /* define height to restrict */
    p = $('#p'), /* your element depending on whatever selector */
    fs = parseInt(p.css('font-size')); /* get the current font size */

while (p.height() > threshold) { /* while height is more than threshold */
    p.css({'font-size': fs-- }); /* reduce the font-size */
}
p.height(threshold); /* adjust the final height to clean up */
```

You might need to adjust the final height a little bit after the loop.

**Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ab6m7yh1/2/**

**Demo Snippet**:

```js
var threshold = 100;

$('p').each(function() {
    var $self = $(this), 
  fs = parseInt($self.css('font-size'));
    
    while($self.height() > threshold) {
        $self.css({'font-size': fs-- });
    }
    $self.height(threshold);
});
```

```css
p { font-size: 2em; width: 320px; height: auto; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </p>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change the font size of text using the `vw` value, like so:

```
p {
    font-size:3vw;
}
```

I made a post about this some time ago: http://adam-marsden.co.uk/blog/posts/viewport-scaling-divs-and-typography

Comment: Nice tip! Thank you for your share and article.

Comment: This is only relative to the viewport size, not the parent element size

Answer (score 0):

You can use css media queries for this for example you can set each tag to be responsive

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

   h1 {
      font-size: 2,5em;
   }

   h2 {
      font-size: 2em;
   }

   p{
       font-size:1,8em
   }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use bootstrap to make your responsive website - with the `col-md-xx`, the bootstrap will automatically change your paragraph's font size, check this out: 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

In another way - you can add a similar code like this to your style sheet:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    .div-font{font-size:20px}
}
```

Remember to set maximum and minimum width and change the selector name